# SFTP delete files older than x number of days

Tags: sftp, winscp

How can I delete files at sftp older than x number of days? I'm using WinSCP client to connect to the sftp.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this from GUI, select files to be deleted using a file mask with time-constraint (`*<4D` for 4 days) and than just delete them.

Some references:
https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_select
https://winscp.net/eng/docs/file_mask

If you want to automate it, use `rm` command with the same mask:
https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_automation
https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_rm